# Format data of http response inside the code tag in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting html rendered as -

pre,code {    background: #f4f4f4;    border: 1px solid #ddd;    border-left: 3px solid #f36d33;    color: #666;    page-break-inside: avoid;    font-family: monospace;    font-size: 15px;    line-height: 1.6;    margin-bottom: 1.6em;    max-width: 100%;    overflow: auto;    padding: 1em 1.5em;    display: block;    word-wrap: break-word;}

I want the output should be formatted -

```
pre,code {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-left: 3px solid #f36d33;
    color: #666;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

My angular code is -

```
  getAllThreads(): void {
    this.forumService.getAllThreads().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.posts = res.items;
        console.log(this.posts);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.error = err.status;
        this.loading = false;
        if (err.status == 404) {
          this.error = "Something went wrong, Error : 404";
        } else {
          this.error = err.statusText;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Ajax Response
description: "↵↵

CODE:

↵

```
pre,code {    background: #f4f4f4;    border: 1px solid #ddd;    border-left: 3px solid #f36d33;    color: #666;    page-break-inside: avoid;    font-family: monospace;    font-size: 15px;    line-height: 1.6;    margin-bottom: 1.6em;    max-width: 100%;    overflow: auto;    padding: 1em 1.5em;    display: block;    word-wrap: break-word;}
```

↵↵

---

↵"

[image]
Here you can see enter icon is coming but when the page is being rendered its not taking it as enter and thus not coming in new line. I want it should be newline and thus will look like formatted.

I know stackoverflow editor is making this enter icon here because actually it is enter.

Please advise.
[image]

I want it to be -
formatted code i.e. after ; there should be newline

Comment: How can we achieve this, using map method? If yes then can you please guide me.

In normal jquery if we need to play with ajax we did it with .replace method or any regex but how I can do it in angular?

Comment: Have you tried innerHTML ?

Comment: <p [innerHTML]="post.content">content.</p> this is my html file code

Comment: So you mean style only not being applied?

Comment: I am not asking in terms of styles or css, I am asking about how to modify http response or any idea why innerHTML is not working properly, response has enter but html is rendering as space and thus instead of new line , text is coming on same line.